# How to click on a check box in a new window through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to make this check box click but not I'm not able to click on check box.

Please send me the xpath or css

[image]

I tried:

```
xpath
//div//*[@id='thCheckBox']

.//*[@id='searchOrderModel']/div/div/div[3]/div/button[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a label next to the checkbox. You can try to click on the label then it will click the checkbox using below x-path.

```
//label[@for='thCheckbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided and your question as the *Check Box* is on a new window to `click()` on the *Check Box* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *Check Box* to be clickable and you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  "table.table.table-hover.dataTable#orderNoDropdown label[for='thCheckBox']"
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  "//table[@class='table table-hover dataTable' and @id='orderNoDropdown']//label[@for='thCheckBox']"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned it is new window, then you will have to **switch** to new **windows** in order to interact with the web element. after reaching to new window you can use this code :

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());  
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

//Now you have focused on new Windows , and you can interact with check box now :

```
WebElement checkBox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("thCheckBox")));  
checkBox.click();
```

Then again you have to switch back to page from where you went to this Page, if you want that.

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo.windows(tabs.get(0));
```